# Filtering CustomListItem with checkbox in sap.m.List works but the checkbox lose their selected state on filtering

Tags: sapui5

The checkboxes in the CustomListItem lose their selected state as soon as I filter them, could someone please help me with it?

View:

```
<CustomListItem id="itemList">
  <CheckBox class="sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd" text="{name}" select="onSelectionChange"/>
</CustomListItem>
```

Controller:

```
const value: string = event.getParameter("newValue");
const list: sap.m.List = this.getView().byId("listToFilter") as sap.m.List;
const listBinding = list.getBinding("items") as sap.ui.model.json.JSONListBinding;
listBinding.filter([new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value)]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the 'selected' property of CheckBox in the same way as 'text'